# Can someone suggest books on mathematics and problem solving which nurtures the reader?

Tags: reference-request, problem-solving, book-recommendation

Can someone suggest books on mathematics and problem solving which nurtures the reader like [Alexander Soifer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Soifer)'s books?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which topic in mathematics?

Comment: Nurture in like spoonfeeding ?

Comment: @qwerty Problem solving.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM i mean to say not a kind of theorem-proof style, but interacting with the reader.

Comment: if interested in Abstract algebra, then J.A.Gallian is a book for you

Comment: @qwerty Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Maybe for users who are not familiar with Soifer's style, you might expand a bit on what exactly you are looking for in those books. (This might also improve your chance of getting good answers.)

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is Mathematics and Plausible Reasoning by Polya.  It's casual and focused on how to analyze things rather than specific techniques or theories.  It's sort of a more advanced version of How To Solve It, his more famous book (which you should also read if you haven't).

If you're interested in contests, my first introduction was Problem Solving Through Problems by Larson, which is aimed at relative noobs.  But once you get your feet wet you should really focus almost completely on practicing with actual problems.  There's no training like experience.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion